# How to cancel the problem when exponent n+1

Tags: calculus

[image]

Hi, I am working on this problem, but I am not sure how to cancel the exponent n+1

does it deal with the infinity?

[image]

if it does, how to solve it?

thank

Comment: You should **never** use $\infty$ in arithmetic, it is meaningless: $\infty/\infty$, $a^\infty$, $\infty-\infty$: they are all nonsense.  The only place, at this stage, where you should use the symbol is after an arrow: $n\to\infty$.  Later on you may learn things like $\sum^\infty$ and $\int^\infty$, but they all come back to the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You take the limit:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\dfrac{-1}{4}\right|=\left|\dfrac{-1}{4}\right|=\dfrac{1}{4}$$
Since $\dfrac{a^{n+1}}{a^n}=a$. Your second expression is meaningless, since $\left|\dfrac{3(-1)^{\infty+1}}{4^{\infty+1}}\dfrac{4^\infty}{(-1)^n3}\right|$ has no proper defined meaning.

Comment: the original problem is about infinite series, so I just paste the part I don't know, and thank you. And can you explain how do you take off the 3(−1)^n+1?

Comment: @user47103 The $3$s cancel out. Since $\dfrac{a^{n+1}}{a^n}=a$ (let $a=-1$), I cancel out the $3(-1)^{n+1}$.

Comment: oh, I got it, you substitute the n and a to got the answer, ok, thank you

Comment: @user47103 If this answer was what you wanted, then you can click on the check mark next to the answer to mark it as "answered".

Answer (score 2):

The expressions as given are meaningless - what exactly does $$\frac{4^{\infty}}{4^{\infty + 1}}$$ mean (or even $\infty + 1$)? Rather, you should do some algebra to simplify until you're left with something that you can consider more easily. Notice that

$$\frac{4^{n}}{4^{n + 1}} = \frac 1 4$$

so that your complicated fraction can be simplified to

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac 1 4$$

Now we have the limit of a constant sequence.

Comment: thank you, your second equation helped alot